# -$test = new stdClass() - causes an error, but isn't this a bug in PHP?

Tags: php

We can do something like this in PHP:

```
-$test = 42;//notice a minus sign before $test
```

On the other hand, this code:

```
-$test = new stdClass()
```

brings an error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

And OK, that's fine, but why PHP allows to put a "-" (minus sign) before a variable declaration? Note, that this is a first appearance of $test. It doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-$test = 42;` is almost similar to `$test = -42;`, which is normal behavior.

By `-$test = new stdClass()` you are trying to assign `-` sign to an object, wgich is illegal and that's why you are getting that error.

Comment: That's not entirely true, because var_dump($test) gives int(42) (a positive number). Besides I'm not asking about the error - I'm asking why declaring a variable like this is OK in PHP. I don't know any language where this is possible, for example in JavaScript it gives: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: @konrad_firm `var_dump(-$test)` would print `int(-42)`.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but you said "-$test = 42; is similar to $test = -42;" while it isn't, otherwise var_dump($test) would give -42. And it doesn't. I still believe it's a bug :) This "-" before a variable changes nothing in this case, and I think it's illegal in all languages except PHP (I'm sure it's illegal at least in C,C++,Javascript).

Comment: But OK, +1, because only you bothered to answer :)

Comment: @devpro you said "at least", so it looks like you agree with Sougata, And this means it is probably a correct answer, even if I don't understand it :( So I'm forced to accept it :)

Comment: @konard_firm no one force u to accept this.. If its solve your problem than accept otherwise no.